# What do we mean by "argument type for %p format specifier is "void*"?

Tags: c++, c

So far, to print out the values of pointers (addresses) I have, (correctly or incorrectly) used the `%u` format specifier. In this regard, what does `%p` specifier mean? Does it print out the value of pointers of only `void*` type? I tried this `%p` specifier to print out an integer pointer and it seems the output is a hexa-decimal value. Is it wrong to use `%p` to print integer or character pointer values? Please tell me something about `%p` format specifier. Web resources only left me confused.

I have sourced the statement in the question from the following link:

http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~rjp/Coursewww/Cwww/format.html

Comment: Other pointers can be implicitly converted to void pointers, but I'm not sure how well that applies in a C variadic function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is for printing the address held by pointers. It works on any pointer type.

Answer (score 4):

The `%u` format 'works' as long as `sizeof(void *) == sizeof(unsigned)`, which is typically true for 32-bit code, but not for 64-bit code.  If you want to keep control of the format (you do not get to control the appearance of `%p`), then you'll want to use `<inttypes.h>` from C99:

```
printf("0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)&object);
```

The macro PRIXPTR gives the correct length modifier for a value of type `uintptr_t` and the conversion specifier `X`.  The type `uintptr_t` is an integer type big enough to hold any pointer.  The `.8` ensures that you get at least 8 hex digits printed, but more if the address is a 64-bit quantity and has bits set in the leading (most significant) 32 bits of the value.

Strictly, if you are going to use `%p`, then (a) you should ensure that the value on the stack is actually a `void *` by casting (because `fprintf()` et al are variadic functions and that conversion won't occur automatically), and (b) there is no cross-platform standard for the format.  It is often equivalent to lower-case hex with no `0x` prefix; some systems generate the `0x` prefix.  In practice, you're usually safe passing an `int *`.

Theoretically, in standard C, there isn't a way to print function pointers; there's no guarantee that a function pointer is the same size as a data pointer.  Fortunately, POSIX steps in and does state that on POSIX systems, function pointers shall be the same size as data pointers.  So, at least on Unix systems, and de facto on Windows systems, you are safe printing data pointers and function pointers.

Comment: You can print a function pointer by accessing the bytes that make it up as `unsigned char`s - essentially treating it as an opaque binary blob.

Comment: Wrong assumption in the first sentence. Using the `%u` format also assumes that the pointer values are stored in the same place as integer values. This isn't the case on e.g. Motorola's 68000 family which had dedicated integer and pointer registers.

Answer (score 1):

`void*` means: "A pointer to somewhere in memory, but I have no idea what type of memory that it is pointing to." This is why the `%p` specifier is `void*`, because you don't care about the *type* only the memory address. It is intended to be used to print addresses. On the other hand `%u` expects the data to be `unsigned int`, while this might work in practice, there is a chance that `void*` and `unsigned int` are different sizes, etc. so it shouldn't be used. Also, as mentioned in the other answer, even though all pointers are convertible to `void*`, `printf` and family of variadic functions technically do not perform this conversion, so casting to `void*` should be done:

```
printf("%p", (void*)&x);
```